# syntax error I get overtime I open terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

When I open terminal I get this error

Is it harming something? How can I fix and get rid of it ?

> Last login: Mon Aug 15 11:44:29 on ttys000
>       -bash: eval: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file

As it is suggested by the answer below I should set -x and here is what I did I did set -x

```
Admins-MBP:~ admin$ set -x
+ set -x
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=r
++ [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=r
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=d
++ [[ d =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=d
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=m
++ [[ m =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=m
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=i
++ [[ i =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=i
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=n
++ [[ n =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=n
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://Admins-MBP/Users/admin
```

then i did

```
Admins-MBP:~ admin$ . .bash_profile
+ . .bash_profile
++ '[' -r /Users/admin/.bashrc ']'
++ source /Users/admin/.bashrc
+++ source /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
++++ export PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION=0.76
++++ PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION=0.76
++++ export PERLBREW_ROOT=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew
++++ PERLBREW_ROOT=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew
++++ [[ -z /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew ]]
++++ [[ -z /Users/admin/.perlbrew ]]
++++ [[ ! -n '' ]]
++++ [[ -f /Users/admin/.perlbrew/init ]]
++++ . /Users/admin/.perlbrew/init
+++++ export PERLBREW_MANPATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man
+++++ PERLBREW_MANPATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man
+++++ export PERLBREW_PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin
+++++ PERLBREW_PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin
+++++ export PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.16.0
+++++ PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.16.0
+++++ export PERLBREW_ROOT=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew
+++++ PERLBREW_ROOT=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew
+++++ export PERLBREW_VERSION=0.74
+++++ PERLBREW_VERSION=0.74
++++ perlbrew_bin_path=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin
++++ [[ -f /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew ]]
++++ perlbrew_command=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew
++++ unset perlbrew_bin_path
++++ __perlbrew_activate
+++++ alias perl
++++ [[ -n '' ]]
++++ [[ -n perl-5.16.0 ]]
++++ __perlbrew_set_env perl-5.16.0
++++ local code
+++++ /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew env perl-5.16.0
++++ code='export PERLBREW_MANPATH="/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man"
export PERLBREW_PATH="/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin"
export PERLBREW_PERL="perl-5.16.0"
export PERLBREW_ROOT="/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew"
export PERLBREW_VERSION="0.76"'
++++ eval 'export PERLBREW_MANPATH="/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man"
export PERLBREW_PATH="/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin"
export PERLBREW_PERL="perl-5.16.0"
export PERLBREW_ROOT="/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew"
export PERLBREW_VERSION="0.76"'
+++++ export PERLBREW_MANPATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man
+++++ PERLBREW_MANPATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man
+++++ export PERLBREW_PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin
+++++ PERLBREW_PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin
+++++ export PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.16.0
+++++ PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.16.0
+++++ export PERLBREW_ROOT=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew
+++++ PERLBREW_ROOT=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew
+++++ export PERLBREW_VERSION=0.76
+++++ PERLBREW_VERSION=0.76
++++ __perlbrew_set_path
++++++ manpath
+++++ __perlbrew_purify /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
+++++ local path patharray outsep
+++++ IFS=:
+++++ read -ra patharray
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s /usr/local/share/man
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/usr/share/man
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/opt/X11/share/man
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
+++++ outsep=:
++++ export MANPATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
++++ MANPATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
+++++ __perlbrew_purify /Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
+++++ local path patharray outsep
+++++ IFS=:
+++++ read -ra patharray
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s /Users/admin/.rbenv/shims
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/opt/local/bin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/opt/local/sbin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/usr/local/bin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/usr/bin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/bin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/usr/sbin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/sbin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/opt/X11/bin
+++++ outsep=:
+++++ for path in '"${patharray[@]}"'
+++++ case "$path" in
+++++ printf %s :/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
+++++ outsep=:
++++ export PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
++++ PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
++++ hash -r
+++ export PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
+++ PATH=/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
++ export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
++ PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
+++ rbenv init -
++ eval 'export PATH="/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '\''/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'\''
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}source' /Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
+++ export PATH=/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
+++ PATH=/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/admin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin
+++ export RBENV_SHELL=bash
+++ RBENV_SHELL=bash
+++ source /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash
++++ complete -F _rbenv rbenv
+++ command rbenv rehash
-bash: eval: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local url_path=
++ local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=
++ (( i = 0 ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=U
++ [[ U =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=U
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=e
++ [[ e =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=e
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=r
++ [[ r =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=r
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=s
++ [[ s =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=s
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=/
++ [[ / =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=/
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=a
++ [[ a =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=a
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=d
++ [[ d =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=d
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=m
++ [[ m =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=m
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=i
++ [[ i =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=i
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ ch=n
++ [[ n =~ [/._~A-Za-z0-9-] ]]
++ url_path+=n
++ (( ++i ))
++ (( i < 12 ))
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://Admins-MBP/Users/admin
Admins-MBP:~ admin$
```

Comment: To those wanting to close the question, a syntax error in `.bashrc` is a programming problem.

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 33 of one of your start up scripts. Can you post the contents of `.bashrc` and `.bashprofile` (both in your home directory).

Comment: @JeremyP I posted above. it does not find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely coming from your `.bashrc` or `.bashprofile`.

You can try to diagnose the root cause by first using `set -x`, this will cause your shell to trace all the commands being executed. Then you can source the files again by doing `. .bashrc` and `. bash_profile` and see what's going on.

Comment: I did as you said and I close it and opened again the terminal I got the same error message

Comment: These commands will not magically fix your problem but help diagnose it. One of the source commands should reproduce the error, paste the last few lines of the resulting output into your question so people will have a chance to see what the cause of the issue could be.

Comment: thanks I appreciate your help , I did not down vote your answer ! I appreciate any help I get so thanks although it did not help me to solve it

Comment: You are missing a dot in front within the source command, it's `. .bashrc`, not `.bashrc`.

Comment: when I do Admins-MBP:~ admin$ . .bash_profile
-bash: eval: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Admins-MBP:~ admin$

Comment: when I do Admins-MBP:~ admin$ . .bashrc
Admins-MBP:~ admin$

Comment: OK, don't forget to `set -x`, then do `. .bash_profile` again and include the last few lines of the output in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121081/discussion-between-dorian-and-nik).